# How to control source files in VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

This seems like a painfully simple question that would be 3 seconds of googling away, but here I am after days of head scratching.  I have a collection of c files and headers saved in

- `F:\public\code\tlfps02c\embedded\src\`

some of which require include files saved in

- `F:\public\code\watt32\inc\`

but I also have old code I don't want to use saved in

- `F:\public\code\tlfps02c\embedded\src_old\`

The problem is Visual Studio Code is using definitions from `src_old` and I can't figure out how to control this.  I don't have any files open from this folder so from what I've read it shouldn't be finding these files.  I need to exclude these files and would prefer to achieve this within VSCode and not with some heavy handed file management changes

Comment: You should use source control and delete the "old" folder

Comment: OK next dumb question, what does "use source control" mean?  I've always used netbeans previously and never ran into this.  I certainly cannot delete my last working version, and regardless I will always have adjacent folders with conflicting definitions as each project reuses existing code with changes.

Comment: It means use something like [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) or [`subversion`](https://subversion.apache.org/). VS Code supports integration of either near-seamlessly. That probably falls under your definition of "heavy-handed", but nonetheless if you're not using such management, you should be.

Comment: This seems major.  Could you possibly recommend a guide to this kind of management?

Comment: I am surprised you're using VSCode for C development. It really isn't suitable for C even with the given extensions, you may consider using a more robust IDE like [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)

Comment: @Narm Why not? It’s perfectly fine for that.

Comment: Install git and source tree. Recommending you to check some very basic videos in youtube. Then you are good to go